# What are the points of intersection?

Tags: calculus

Consider the graphs of $y=x^{1/3},y=\dfrac{x-2}{3}$. Find the region enclosed between the two graphs.

I know the area of the region is $\int^b_ax\,dy$ or $\int^d_cy\,dx$, but I have no idea *where* the two graphs intersect. I know one intersection point is $x=8$, but where's the other?

Answer (score 1):

Set $x^{1/3} = (x-2)/3$. Multiply by 3, cube both sides and figure out that you can factor the cubic equation as $(x-8)(x+1)^2 = 0$. Hence, the second point of intersection is $x=-1$. Verify that $(-1)^{1/3} = -1$ and $(-1-2)/3 = -1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't see the intersection point, and so was a bit perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for x and then setting $y^3=3y+2$ gives $y^3-3y-2=0$, and from your work you know that $y-2$ is a factor of the left side (since $y=2$ when $x=8$).

Now one way to find the remaining factor is to divide, or you can try to find another root by inspection.